# Dockerfile, make multiple commands (CMD) but waiting for DB prompt?

Tags: docker, terminal, xampp, mariadb

So I'm making a dockerfile and I want it to set up a project and import a database after that. I'm using XAMPP and the included MariaDB. I know I need to use CMD for the import since XAMPP must be running. I'm trying to import the DB by running a sql script that does the job in the DB prompt.

I tried using && and ; for chaining commands in a single line but it won't work since it tries to run all commands on the terminal prompt before waiting on MariaDB prompt. Any Ideas?

This is my docker file and last line is my attempt to import the database:

```
FROM cswl/xampp

COPY . /opt/lampp/htdocs/

WORKDIR /opt/lampp/htdocs/

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | /opt/lampp/bin/php &&\
  /opt/lampp/bin/php composer.phar install

RUN curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/careers-picpay/lista_relevancia_1.txt --output db/lista_relevancia_1.txt &&\
  curl http://s3.amazonaws.com/careers-picpay/lista_relevancia_2.txt --output db/lista_relevancia_2.txt &&\
  curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/careers-picpay/users.csv.gz --output db/users.csv.gz

RUN gzip -d db/users.csv.gz

CMD /opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root && source ./initdb.sql
```

UPDATE:
So I also tried to replace my two commands with one with the MariaDB -e option, for executing a line after login... Didn't work, database wasn't created and I don't know why. This is the command:

```
CMD /opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root -e "source ./initdb.sql"
```

Comment: Commonly you would run the database in one container and the application that uses it (XAMPP) in another. It's considered not good practice and it's problematic to run multiple processes in a single container. In my experience, it's also challenging to coordinate database initialization in containers. I suspect your `CMD` is starting the `mysql` process and getting no further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**

With the MariaDB official image one should just copy the init script (`initdb.sql`) in the directory `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. 
See [MariaDB Docker Quick Reference](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/mariadb/). Files in that directory are executed in alphabetical order when the container is created and initialized.

With the XAMPP image, it seems that you have to do it manually. This is definitely not an elegant solution but it should work.

Replace the `ENTRYPOINT` script of the image with this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

/opt/lampp/lampp start

# wait for mysql to be ready
while ! /opt/lampp/bin//mysql --protocol TCP  -e "show databases;"; do sleep 2; done

# initialize the database
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root -e "source /init.sql"

## Run tail so we don't exit
/usr/bin/tail -f /opt/lampp/logs/php_error_log
```

This will wait for `mysql` to be ready before executing the `source` command.

Add to the `Dockerfile` the following to copy the initialization sql script and override the `ENTRYPOINT`:

```
FROM cswl/xampp
...

COPY init.sql /init.sql

COPY init.sh /init.sh
RUN chmod +x /init.sh

ENTRYPOINT  ["/init.sh"]
```

Comment: This works only for MariaDB official image. As you can see in my Dockerfile, I'm using a non-official XAMPP image.

Comment: I somehow missed that. That wasn't a really useful answer and I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

you may use [wait-for-it.sh](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh) to check if DB is up by adding it to `CMD`:

```
CMD ["path/to/wait-for-it.sh", "localhost:3306", "-t", "6000", "--", "YOUR ACTUAL COMMAND"]
```

you may at first copy the script to your container.

here is [more info](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)